# why does this get an error and this doesn't?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm working through a hackerrank problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kaprekar-numbers/problem

and kept having to deal with this error:
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

the **line 12 of code in mine that churned out error**, is in the working code too. So i don't understand why mine didn't work :( please help

this is my code:

```
a = input()
b = input()
l = []
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    s = i*i
    s = str(s)
    if i == 1:
        l.append(i)
    length = len(s)
    if length <= 1:
        pass
    temp = int(s[0:length/2]) + int(s[length/2:]) #error came from this line
    if temp == i:
        l.append(i)
    else: 
        pass

if not l:
    print "INVALID RANGE"
else:
    print " ".join(map(str, l))
```

and this is the one that works:

```
def kaprekar(i):
    if i == 1:
        return True
    s = i ** 2
    s = str(s)
    length = len(s)
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return False
    temp = int(s[0:length/2]) + int(s[length/2:])
    if temp == i:
        return True
    else:
        return False
a = input()
b = input()
l = []
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    if kaprekar(i):
        l.append(i)
if not l:
    print "INVALID RANGE"
else:
    print " ".join(map(str, l))
```

Comment: You have to convert the user input to int. To do so, use `a = int(input())` and the same for `b`. I wonder how the `for i in range(a, b + 1):` in the second code working

Comment: What are the inputs you use when testing your code? The "working" code has safety checks in place that you don't have (line 2 and 7). Those cover corner cases where `int(s[0:length/2])` would fail. E.g., if `len(s) == 1`, `s[0:length/2]` becomes `s[0:0]`, which is the empty string. The error message says the empty string is not a valid number, so my guess is you missed the safety checks.

Comment: I think you're confusing `pass` with `continue`.

Comment: @molbdnilo you're right. I changed it to continue and it worked. I feel so stupid

Answer (score 0):

```
if length <= 1:
    pass
```

`pass` literally doesn't do anything, so this check doesn't do anything. Whether the `length` is or isn't `<= 1`, you're proceeding to `int(s[length/2:])`, which will produce said error in case the string *is* too short.

However, `return False` exits the function and the following code will not execute, so that check protects you from trying to process short strings.